# Devise official wiki for omniauth with facebook not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed the devise official wiki to integrate devise with facebook through omniauth.

I am able to login with my facebook account but somehow I am unable to save additional data from facebook's omniauth callback.

Note that I literally copied everything on [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)

Please look at my current user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, 
                  :fb_raw

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
      user
    else # Create a user with a stub password. 
      User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && \
          session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        # Here you can save all the info you want including networks and education 
        user.email = data["email"]
        user.fb_raw = data['raw_info']
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The problem here is that self.new_with_session is **never** invoked. I placed a throw exception clause right before `super.tab` to prove that my hypothesis.

Does anyone know a work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new_with_session` is call on `DeviseRegistrationController` so it's not in `OmniauthCallbacksController` so it's normal to never be called during the login by Facebook.